# creating a dataframe from a dictionary of tuples in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data structure :

```
word1 [('date', freq) , ('date',freq) , ...]
word2 [('date',freq) , ('date',freq) , ...]
```

and so on.for analyzing the time series , I want to create a dataframe. I can not figure out the best way to do it  as I'm quite new to python(and I apologize for that). should I use:

```
classmethod DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', dtype=None)
```

Comment: Is `word1` a **list** of tuples? Where is the dictionary? What should the final DataFrame look like?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, the whole file is dictionary of words , which words are keys and values are list of tuples (Date and freq) . actually I'm not sure what I want is a DataFrame with each word as raw and each tuple as columns . but the problem is that the number of tuples are not equal for all the words. so I'm trying to figure out which DataFrame is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of possible ways to start, but assuming a structure of words as

```
words
Out[203]: 
[[('2000-01-01', 1), ('2000-01-02', 5)],
 [('2000-01-01', 2), ('2000-01-02', 4)]]
```

the following is a natural starting point.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0), columns=['date', 'word', 'freq'])
i = 0
for j, word in enumerate(words):
    for d, f in word:
        df.loc[i] = [d, j, f]
        i += 1
```

`df.loc[i]` will append new rows. If you know the total number of entries from the start, you could change `index=range(0)` to the correct value. Next steps would probably be

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index(['date', 'word'], drop=True)
                freq
date       word     
2000-01-01 0       1
2000-01-02 0       5
2000-01-01 1       2
2000-01-02 1       4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but actually my data structure is a dic, in which values are tuples. and I think it will be more efficent to have a DataFrame like an inverted index , in which given a word and a time granularity I can plot the frequency graph. I'm not sure which way is the most efficent , I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with an inverted index: Could you extend your question to supply expected outcome? As for the data structure, I don't think it should be a problem to adapt that.